# Run (.Net) Donet Core 3.x on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and run ASP projects with Plesk

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

We are trying to install the .Net Core 3.x on our Ubuntu 16.04 server, but somehow we can install the Dotnet Core 3.x but can't see the ASP page after publishing the project.

We use Nginx & Apache on our dedicated server. Does anyone have a Step-By-Step installation Guide for this?

Somehow the Donet Core is installed on our Linux server but the project wont run on the server.

Comment: You need to explain more than "can't see the ASP page after publishing the project". After running `dotnet publish`, what exactly did you do? What happens if you run `dotnet run` directly to launch the web app?

Comment: If I run dotnet run in Putty i get the 'Hello world' output with the next commands : 1. 'dotnet new console -o app' 2. 'dotnet run'. I just can't get the pages on a domain in Plesk or trough Linux.

Comment: `dotnet new console` creates a console application, so even if you build and run it, there would be no pages simply due to the facts that it is not a web application.

Comment: I made a simple .Net Core webapplication in Visual Studio 2019 and put the 'netcoreapp3.0' -> 'linux-x64' content to the root of my domain and just wont see the webpage run on my domain.

Comment: That's right. You won't see any pages by copying those (output of `dotnet build`) to another server, because they are not effectively the things to be deployed. `dotnet publish` is a step you cannot skip, and Microsoft does have articles on that, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: So if i want to create a project in Windows with Visual Studio's 2019 and create a 'ASP.Net Core Web Application' how do I deploy the project to my Linux server? Like the output i have on the 'https://localhost:44392/'.